# Import Maven multi-module project into Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, project, multi-module

How do I properly import a Maven multi-module project into Eclipse? When I import a new Maven project and select the parent pom, I can see the submodules under the parent pom which are visible in the package explorer and project explorer. However, they are presented as a deep directory structure, as if Eclipse doesn't know they are Java projects.

When I expand the submodule project, I don't see the Java package shortcuts as I would have if I opened a single Maven project. I only see it as a deep directory structure. How do I import a multimodule Maven project and open the submodule project to take advantage of Eclipse Java project features?

Comment: Can you share a screenshots to describe *presented as deep directory structure*  &&  *I expand the submodule project, I don't see the java packages shortcuts*

Answer (score 15):

- Install M2E Plugin from Market if it is not already installed
- From Eclipse IDE choose "File" and "Import" from toolbar. That should
  lead you to a pop up.
- Type "Existing Maven Project", or navigate to this under
  Maven settings.
- Then select the main pom project from the import menu, and be sure
  to select entire tree of projects under it.

Before approaching this clean the IDE from the currently wrong imported project, deleting its Maven root pom project and every submodule, but leave them on the disk obviously.
I don't recommend the "Convert" options as sometimes that doesn't lead to clean results, especially with big and messy projects.

Comment: It sounds like that is what was already done.  As I see it, the submodules aren't selectable.  Only the parent POM project is selectable in Eclipse 2018.09.

Comment: I would agree with @shawn1874 - in my case though I can select individually both parent and modules. When all of them are checked, the environment behavior is as described in the question. When only the modules are selected, they are imported and viewed properly (Java Resources is visible, packages are automatically shown grouped) (Red Hat Developer Studio 12.9.0.GA based on Eclipse)

Comment: @Black.Jack Could you please provide the link of M2E plugin or screenshot? Upon searching in eclipse marketplace, I can see a lot of of plugins (not anyone specific with name as only M2E)

Answer (score 10):

First, import the parent project. Then, right click on it at the package/project explorer, go to **Configure** and then click the **Configure and Detected Nested Projects...**, on the window that will appear click **Finish** and you're gold.

Also worth mentioning, Package Explorer won't show it nested, use Project Explorer instead.

Have a nice day.

Answer (score 5):

For everyone who still have the same issue, follow these steps:

1. Open `Import Existing Maven Project` wizard
2. Select the Parent `POM.xml` only and click `Finish`
3. Foreach child project, `Right Click` on the project folder, then click on `Import` and select his `POM.xml` file

Hope it helps ! Good Luck !

Answer (score 2):

If you are using git or any version control. Clone the repository first in local.

Steps already explain by @Black Jack. Adding image to support

[image]

Answer (score 2):

### Step 1

- Navigate to project folder.
- Open command prompt (or shell)
- Run `mvn eclipse:eclipse`

### Step 2

- Open eclipse IDE
- Open project from `File > Open Projects From File System...`
- Select folder of project containing parent `pom.xml` file

### Step 3

- Run `Project > Clean` from Menu

### Step 4

- Run `File> Restrat` From Menu

Solved my problem in Eclipse 2019-06(4.12.0) and 2018-12(4.10.0)

### Important trick

When you start to search for files in 'open resource' (for example using `Ctrl` + `Shift` + `R`)  eclipse will show file from two address. for example `MySampleFile` will be available under:

- `parent-module/sub-module/src/main/java/.../MySampleFile` and
- `sub-module/src/main/java/.../MySampleFile`

*Use second one*. Opening file with first one will not activate IDE features on that file.

Answer (score 0):

To add a few on top of @BlackJacks answer, ensure that the parent `pom` in the root of the directory that contains sub-projects contains a modules section:

```
<modules>
    <module>module1</module>
    <module>module2</module>
    <module>module3</module>
</modules>
```

So, after the import, unlike *IntelliJ, Eclipse* opens the sub-modules as separate projects, apart from the main root project.

Hope this helps!

Comment: can Eclipse open the sub-modules under main root project? Is there a setting for this?

Answer (score 0):

In my case the name of the main project after I cloned it was the same as the name that would have been used for one of the modules. Therefore, after cloning the project, I added a suffix to it to change it. After that the import worked just fine.

Another way of solving, at least in my case, would have been to use a name template when importing the project, one that would make the name of the module different than the main project:

[image]

This video helped me get back on the track and find what my problem was: https://youtu.be/aF0xP9SXcrE?si=3LDzzb9gbaQwtoaj.

Answer (score -1):

Follow the steps

1. Choose file menu
2. Click on `import`
3. Select project right click then Convert --> Convert to maven project
4. Click on `import` then type or select `Existing Maven Project`

Now your moduled project in you workbench. If you have any query we can discuss.